# Issues with SSL key on CentOS

Tags: centos, ssl

When trying to install a SSL key on my centos server, apache refuses to restart and I see the following errors in my log.

```
[Tue Mar 16 22:32:58 2010] [error] Init: Private key not found
[Tue Mar 16 22:32:58 2010] [error] SSL Library Error: 218710120 error:0D094068:asn1 encoding routines:d2i_ASN1_SET:bad tag
[Tue Mar 16 22:32:58 2010] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Tue Mar 16 22:32:58 2010] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Tue Mar 16 22:32:58 2010] [error] SSL Library Error: 218734605 error:0D09A00D:asn1 encoding routines:d2i_PrivateKey:ASN1 lib
```

What exactly does this mean? Is my SSL key bad?  If so, what is the correct way to upload the key to the server?  I just opened the crt file in notepad and copied the data out and saved it over ssh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check

`SSLCertificateFile` and

`SSLCertificateKeyFile`

in /etc/http/conf/httpd.conf are both pointing at the correct files.

Check that the `SSLCertificateKeyFile` is a key with ownership set to root:root and permissions set to 400.

Sounds like you have the .crt in place but not the .key.

See the [Apache SSL FAQ](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_faq.html) for more details.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the default SSL key/cert that CentOS attempts to load is usually defined in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`, and can confuse things. (I always disable the default certificate).

Comment: Richard, I checked both the ownership and the permissions and they seem to be good.  Apache still won't start up and I'm getting the same errors.

Comment: Joe, How do I disable the default cert in ssl.conf?

Comment: Yummm , Can I just check you have a key file that is in the correct location defined by SSLCertificateKeyFile and that it is the key for the crt file defined by SSLCertificateFile.

Comment: Richard, Take a look at the original post.  I added my httpd.conf settings.

Comment: Also, Yes the key file exists and it should be the correct key for the crt file.

Comment: I re-did everything from scratch and I was able to resolve the issue. However, when going to https://mydomain.com I see a warning for untrusted site now... hmmm

Comment: I'm all set now! Thanks for putting me in the right direction!

Answer (score -1):

Instal Apache mod ssl

```
# yum install mod_ssl
```

Go to certs folder in centos 6

```
# cd /etc/ssl/certs/
```

Regenerate Private Key and CSR with the help of following OpenSSL command

```
# openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout namhuy_net.key -out namhuy_net.csr
```

Get the CA Root Certificate from Verisign, Thawte, Globalsign, Comodo. After you purchase a cert from those vendor, you will get an email w/ cert files. Upload those files to

```
/etc/ssl/certs/
```

Save the combined file as namhuy_net.pem. The .pem file is now ready to use.

The SSL configuration file for Apache is where I ended up putting the configurations for my server.

```
# nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
```

Edit lines

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/namhuy_net.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/namhuy_net.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/namhuy_net.pem
```

Restart httpd service

```
# service httpd restart
```

Source: http://namhuy.net/760/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-centos-for-apache.html

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED in REDHAT and Centos Check yoyr Selinux disable it then tray restart httpd it will start without  ssl cert missing error.

Comment: Firstly, this question already has an accepted answer. Secondly, your solution is not good - disabling Selinux is not a solution - at best it is a poor workaround!